# feedparser doesn't give lat long with NOAA xml

Tags: python, xml, feedparser, noaa

Using the example url given on the [NOAA rest](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/mdl/survey/pgb_survey/dev/rest.php) site:

`http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php?listZipCodeList=20910+25414`

And the below code:

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php?listZipCodeList=20910+25414')
print d
```

Output:

```
{'feed': {'dwml': {'xsi:nonamespaceschemalocation': u'http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd', 'nonamespaceschemalocation': u'http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd', 'version': u'1.0'}}, 'status': 200, 'version': u'', 'encoding': u'us-ascii', 'bozo': 0, 'headers': {'content-length': '294', 'expires': 'Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:16:54 GMT', 'server': 'Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)', 'connection': 'close', 'cache-control': 'max-age=180', 'date': 'Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:13:54 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/xml'}, 'href': u'http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php?listZipCodeList=20910+25414', 'namespaces': {u'xsi': u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', u'xsd': u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'}, 'entries': []}
```

The `<latLonList>` is missing. I see it in the xml, so why isn't it in the feedparser dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feedparser module is for parsing feeds (e.g., RSS, ATOM, and RDF); to parse general xml, try [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Here is a simple example

```
import urllib
from lxml import etree

noaa_xml = urllib.urlopen('http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php?listZipCodeList=20910+25414').read()
root = etree.fromstring(noaa_xml)
print root[0].text
```